# Слово "поДскользнуться"

Tags: орфоэпия

Ото всех слышу, что именно так говорят — с буквой Д, и я сам тоже так всегда говорил, пока в словаре не обнаружил просто "поскользнуться". Однако я и дальше продолжаю говорить с Д вроде.

Так почему же все говорят "по**д**скользнуться", а в словаре между тем такого слово нету даже как разговорного?! А-а, нет, на Академике всё-таки нашёл, но в Грамоте нету. И вообще, просто интересно, говорит ли кто-то "поскользнуться" из тех, кто прочитает мой вопрос. Это что, старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?

Comment: И ещё, я буду благодарен тому, кто подскажет мне насчёт пунктуации в последнем предложении. Не наставил я там лишних запятых?

Comment: Я говорю "поскользнуться", без "д".

Comment: Интересно, спасибо!)

Comment: Конечно, то, что **я** так говорю, не означает правильность. :-/

Comment: Я всё понимаю, просто я просил тех, кто так говорит, сказать об этом, интересно увидеть реальные примеры. Поэтому и спасибо. :)

Comment: Вот ещё интересный результат: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Странно как-то...

Comment: Виктор, а насчёт запятых не подскажете?

Comment: Выделение слов "старая форма" запятыми оправдано, по-моему, потому что это - уточняющая конструкция.  Не было бы "что" - не надо было бы выделять.  Выделение "и раньше только так говорили" необходимо, потому что это - самостоятельная часть ССП со своим подлежащим и сказуемым, мне думается. Последние два слова - продолжение основного предложения "старая форма или нет".  Так что всё, мне кажется, нормально.  Но я не знаток.

Comment: Иными словами, можно было написать: "Это что, старая форма или нет?".  Или "Это старая форма или нет?", при этом некоторые запятые уходят.

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор! А разве того, что "и раньше только так говорили" — самостоятельная часть ССП, недостаточно для того чтобы поставить запятую. Я как раз хотел понять, так это или нет. То есть выходит, что запятая в любом случае должна быть независимо от того, надо отделять "старую форму" в конце запятой или нет, правильно?

Comment: Запятая после "что" нужна, потому что "старая форма или нет" - уточнение.  Запятые по обеим сторонам "и раньше только так говорили" нужны, потому что это часть ССП.  Но я могу ошибаться...

Comment: Что она нужна после "что", в этом у меня не было как раз сомнений. В предыдущем комментарии я говорил о следующей запятой.

Comment: Возможно, следует отдельный вопрос создать из этого обсуждения...

Comment: Да ладно, я надеюсь, что Вы правы, что я прав. :)))) Хотя попробую, чтобы понять обоснование запятых точно.

Comment: Я говорю "поскользнулся", но возможно, в раннем детстве меня переучили, когда учили читать.

Comment: Читайте больше, книги, газеты, журналы, вслушивайтесь как говорят грамотные люди - никогда не будете мучиться подобными пустяками. Мало ли неграмотных вокруг нас, и что же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Так почему же все говорят "подскользнуться", а в словаре между тем 
такого слово нету даже как разговорного?!
```

В некоторых как разговорное есть. А почему говорят, можно объяснить, как и в паре постричь (сделать причёску) — подстричь (слегка укоротить, подровнять), одним из значений приставки *под* — «проявление действия в слабом или незаметном, скрытом, незаконченном виде». Например, покрасить значит «покрыть краской», подкрасить — «покрасить слегка». Так, может, подскользнуться воспринимается как «слегка поскользнуться»?

Помню, до института тоже спотыкалась на этом слове, в словарь смотрела, как правильно писать, потому что хотелось произнести этот "Д".

Часто делают ошибки и в слове почерк, так и норовят подчерк написать, не вдумываясь в значение: подчерк - от подчеркнуть, почерк - почеркал, т. е. написАл.

Comment: "постричь" еще можно воспринять как "какое-то время стричь". Как в поиграть, поделать, покататься и т.д.

Comment: "Так, может, подскользнуться воспринимается как «слегка поскользнуться»?" Навряд ли... Можно поскользнуться сильно или слабо, но упадёшь ты или нет, зависит от твоей ловкости.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: поскользнуться

Скользить - поска́льзываться - поскользнуться (=заскользив, потерять равновесие, споткнуться на скользком месте). Приставка ПО со значением начала действия.

**Пояснение**

Приставка ПО является многозначной (начало действия, завершенность действия, действие в течение определенного времени, неполное действие и т.д.), но можно определить ее обобщенное значение как направленность на совершение действия определенного характера.

Приставка ПОД также является многозначной с обобщенным значением действия, направленного в пространстве снизу вверх или значения добавления, подчиненности, сопровождения, приближения, неполноты действия.

В принципе в ненормативном глаголе "подскользнуться" можно усмотреть добавочность или неполноту действия по отношению к глаголу "скользить", поэтому и встречается такой вариант глагола.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера! Главное, что меня интересовало, — это почему большинство так говорит.

Comment: Большинство *как* говорит?  И откуда такая уверенность?

Comment: По крайней мере мне так кажется по наблюдениям.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я тоже так говорю и от других слышу. Даже не знал что в словарях "ПОскользнуться". Значит словари устарели. Я так считаю.

Comment: Большинство говорит "поскользнуться". Просто не замечаете. А вообще, говорят по разному, потому и называется "простая речь", "просторечие". Главное - как пишут. Есть выверенный язык, литературный, и есть целое поле просторечных вариантов