# Запятые в предложении (1)

Tags: пунктуация

***Это что, старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Правильно ли я расставил запятые и как их обосновать? В первой после "что" я не сомневаюсь, интересуют две оставшиеся.

Почему я так расставил? Я выделил "и раньше только так говорили" как отдельную часть ССП, которую можно выбросить из предложения, то есть можно сказать просто "старая форма или нет".

+++

Про обособление *старой формы* почему-то стало не так очевидно теперь: я понимаю, что после *это что* нужна запятая, а в конце уже сомневаюсь, действительно ли она нужна.

Comment: Артем, интересный вопрос,  и ответить на него можно нестандартно. учитывая не только правила, но и мелодику русской речи. Я чуть позже дам свой вариант ответа и остальных призываю  к тому же. Хорошо бы только ярче выделить само предложение, а то его плохо видно.

Comment: Замечательно, Шарон, спасибо вам большое заранее!)

Comment: Кстати, для большей интриги....  Зачетную мысль я собираюсь взять из вашего вопроса, если кто-нибудь еще раньше не догадается. Реклама, реклама,,,

Comment: Заинтриговали)))

Comment: *а в конце уже сомневаюсь, действительно ли она нужна* — если "раньше только так говорили" было импровизацией в процессе спрашивания, то запятая как раз это показывает. Отсутствие запятой уместно, если планировалось заранее спросить таким образом.

Comment: @Sharon Примечание: "и раньше только так говорили" вообще не канает как вставная конструкция, это не по-русски. Надеюсь, что не это "зачётная мысль".

Comment: У меня зачетная мысль по грамматике, а содержание уточните у автора.

Comment: Примечание 2: ссылка на предыдущий элемент ("только так") обычно способствует следствию, присоединению, но не в этом случае.

Comment: Примечание 3: при отсутствии запятой, если даже одно из сказанного неверно (это не старая форма или раньше не только так говорили), то тогда получается "или нет".

Comment: Привет всем! Прочитал всё мельком, интересно тут у вас. Хотелось бы поучаствовать, но, видимо, не в этот раз...

Comment: Привет, Александр! А почему не получится?

Comment: Не получится из-за занятости в других делах ("из-за за..." – хм!). А еще, если честно, мне непонятен смысл всей фраз: "говорили раньше только так" о чём? – о том, что это старая форма?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Хм, и здесь обнаружилась двусмысленность. Нет — раньше только старую форму употребляли. А вот ваше многоточие в скобках понять не получается. Похоже на матюк, но не подставляется ничего.

Comment: *"говорили раньше только так" о чём?* — это о слове *поскользнуться* из [этого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419361/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%94%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f) вопроса.

Comment: Где ударение в "старая форма"? У меня на "форма", у Sharon на "старая".

Comment: У меня тоже на *старая.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В качестве заключительного зачетного варианта**  (уже без комментариев)

1. Это предложение **не решает общего вопроса** о постановке запятой перед союзом ИЛИ в простых предложениях из ответа Веры: *Дядя в вас влюблён, или нет? Можешь шагу прибавить, или силёнок нет? Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?*

Оно имеет более сложную структуру и **свое собственное решение.**

2. Предложение начинается **вопросительной конструкцией** «это что», вот подобные примеры из Нацкорпуса: Это что, бунт?   Это что, юмор? Это что тебе, ресторан? Это что ж, порода такая? Это что, порядок?
3. А дальше мы имеем еще **три вопросительных предложения**, так что получается всего четыре. И что мы с ними будем делать?

4   Можно вообще ничего не связывать: Это чтО,  стАрая форма,  и раньше только тАк говорили,  или нЕт?

5. Но в реальной речи так не говорят, и что-то надо объединять. Поэтому делим предложение **на три части:**

***Это чтО, стАрая форма и раньше только тАк говорили,  или нЕт?***

Союз И – соединительный (нет запятой), союз ИЛИ – присоединительный (запятая ставится).

Вариант окончательный, изменяться не будет. 15.09.2021

Comment: Спасибо большое! А присоединительный чем отличается от разделительного? Почему тут именно первый, а не второй, как считала Вера?

Comment: Полагаю, что Вера местоимение «что» относила только к «старой форме», поэтому у нее есть такая запись: Это старая форма и раньше только так говорили, или нет?
Возможно, это неплохой вариант и довольно логичный, так что вы приз присудите Вере (шутка). Все остальные считают, что местоимение «что» относится ко всей фразе, вот и путаются с ней. А союз ИЛИ действительно разделительный (в своей основной профессии), но мне в данном случае его приходится считать присоединительным, чтобы «обойти» правило (по правилу запятая перед разделительным союзом не ставится).

Comment: Вера же начиталась учебников, где разрешается стаить запятую и примеры взяла оттуда.

Comment: _Sharon_, это ведь Ваш **третий** ответ, не правда ли? В предыдущих двух у Вас **везде** перед союзом "и" присутствовала запятая, и Вы _всеми силами_ ее отстаивали. 1. Это чтО, стАрая форма, // и раньше только так говорили, // или нет? Интонация у пояснительного предложения вставочная (второй план речи). 2. Это чтО, стАрая форма, // и раньше только тАк говорили, // или нЕт?.. По это самое решение, то есть авторский выбор подходящей формы. Но если требуется официальное обоснование, то всегда можно сказать, что союз И здесь – присоединительный, а не соединительный.

Comment: Третий ответ? Очень даже возможно.  Я человек творческий и нахожусь в постоянных поисках :)  Да и  речь здесь идет не о правильном варианте, а о лучшем из возможных. Я пока остановилась на этом: Это чтО, стАрая форма и раньше только тАк говорили, или нЕт?  По-моему,  простенько и понятно, без особых претензий.  Хотела тире примерить, но  потом решила, что запятой вполне достаточно. Здесь только союз ИЛИ приходится считать присоединительным, а так всё по правилам.

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Sharon, это ведь Ваш третий ответ, не правда ли?_ === По-моему, четвёртый... 

Comment: Ой, ошибся… Пересчитал ответы: **пятый!**

Comment: @slava1947: по счёту этот был как раз третьим, а потом было ещё два))) Нет, всё-таки потом был ещё один, их только четыре всего, обсчитались)

Comment: А я 4 насчитал. Еще 2 Риммы, oleedd, Andrew Cool и Vera. Итого 9.

Comment: А я не умею считать, спасибо, что вы помогаете :)

Comment: Щас еще плюсы поставлю.

Comment: Ну просто  праздник!  В знак благодарности я придумаю для вас еще какой-нибудь конкурс. Предлагайте веселые темы!

Comment: _Артём Луговой: slava1947: по счёту этот был как раз третьим, а потом было ещё два))) Нет, всё-таки потом был ещё один, их только четыре всего, обсчитались)_ === Не обсчитался! **«Зри в корень!»** (Козьма Прутков).

Comment: А чем больше, тем лучше? Или наоборот?

Comment: _Sharon: А чем больше, тем лучше? Или наоборот?_ === Да ни то ни другое. Просто удивился, что о Вере Вы в третьем лице говорите… 

Comment: @slava1947: Вы что, серьёзно?!

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Вы что, серьёзно?!_ === Конечно! (Но об этом никому… – )

Comment: Договорились)) 

Answer (score 5):

Правильно: Это что, старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?

**Пояснение**

1) Сравнить: Это  старая форма и раньше только так говорили, или нет?

В этом случае **перед одиночным соединительным союзом И не ставится запятая**, так как предложения объединяет вопросительная интонация, а вот **перед ИЛИ ставится запятая**, так как это разделительный союз, который не связывает предложения в общую фразу: Дядя в вас влюблён,   или нет?  Можешь шагу прибавить,  или силёнок нет? 
Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?

2) В приведенном примере "старая форма" **обособляется**, пояснительные
отношения с местоимением ЧТО. Остальные знаки препинания объясняются аналогично п. 1.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера!!

Comment: Я не могу отделатся от ощущения, что нормы и правила, согласно которым ставились запятые в сложносочинённых предложениях, изменились с тех пор как меня учили в школе (давно!).  Конечно, я могу неправильно помнить, но мне всегда казалось, что, если есть своё подлежащее и сказуемое - отделяй, даже при наличии союза "и"...

Comment: Правила Лопатина, знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133. Например: Сквозь дождь лучилось солнце и раскидывалась радуга от края до края.  Это сложное предложение имеет интонацию простого, мы не делаем паузы между двумя предложения, показывая, что общий член "сквозь дождь" относится к обоим предикативным частям. Здесь всё логично.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

***Это что, старая форма и раньше только так говорили – или нет?***

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!

Comment: "Полный список" теперь стал неполным :)

Answer (score 2):

***Это что, старая форма, то есть раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Решение

1. Берем за основу следующее предложение:
   ***Это чтО, стАрая форма или нет?***

Запятую перед одиночным союзом ИЛИ не ставим (вопросительная интонация как общий элемент)

2. Добавляем предложение  с союзом ТО ЕСТЬ, поясняющее значение сочетания «старая норма».

***Это что, старая форма, то есть раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

По Розенталю  пояснительным может быть не только член предложения, но и целое предложение: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

3. Заменяем союз ТО ЕСТЬ присоединительным союзом И с тем же значением

***Это чтО, стАрая форма, // и раньше только так говорили, // или нет?***

Интонация у пояснительного предложения **вставочная** (второй план речи)

4. **Цитата из вопроса как "зачетная мысль"**:  *Почему я так расставил? Я выделил "и раньше только так говорили" как отдельную часть ССП, которую можно выбросить из предложения, то есть можно сказать просто "старая форма или нет".*

Comment: Нет у И значения ТО ЕСТЬ, не воспринимается оно вообще так. И добавляет информацию, а не поясняет её. Ещё проблема в том, что фраза "старая форма" не означает, что раньше только так говорили, поэтому для пояснения оно не подходит, хотя, может, как-то так хотелось выразиться. И ещё: если соединяете вопросительной интонацией, то на "старая форма" не должно быть ударения. Вот как-то с "это что" оно там звучит не по-русски, а с просто "это" возможно. Какое-то совокупное влияние "что" и "или нет". Но ваша попытка довольно интересная.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Шарон! Вчера уже появился ваш ответ, но я прочитал другие комментарии и забыл прочитать ответ. Лопух!) @oleedd: ударение на *стАрая* у меня как раз есть, и мне не кажется, что со "что" звучит не по-русски. А насчёт "то есть"... Заменяет или нет, точно не скажу, но верно то, что эта вставка именно поясняет "старую форму", а не добавляет информацию.

Comment: И ещё, Шарон: можете всё-таки сказать и про другие случаи? Правильно я убрал запятую перед "или нет" в [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427892/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%9f-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e) своём вопросе и действительно должны быть запятые в Вериных примерах про дядю и других?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Имею в виду только "Это что, старая форма или нет?". Вот здесь без ударения звучит не по-русски. Если поясняет, то И не подходит (не относится этот союз к пояснительным). Только в примере про дядю можно без запятой, но это хуже.

Comment: Тогда получается, что после И идёт следствие (а оно требует запятую), но не пояснение.

Comment: Оно живое?)) *Требует запят**ой**,* родительный падеж!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой У меня так не звучит. Опять старомосковская норма.

Comment: Ни фига не старомосковская, а единственно возможный вариант! Открой Грамоту (4-е значение).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Там же в словаре управления указано, что винительный падеж редко или при конкретизации объекта. С тем, что редко, можно согласиться. Это от слов зависит, с некоторыми винительный тоже звучит. Не приходит мне без @ оповещение (здесь).

Comment: [Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427892/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%9f-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e) фраза с "или нет" на конце, Шарон, я про неё спрашивал уже. Не нужна запятая? Спасибо большое за дополнения! Только в словах "по это самое решение" надо что-то исправить.

Comment: Шарон, три раза спросил, а вы не отвечаете! И слова эти надо поправить в другом вашем ответе.

Comment: Артем, не нужна там запятая. Вы ведь не будете спрашивать, почему? А что править – я не знаю, поправьте сами.

Comment: Спасибо! Я бы поправил, но не понял, что вы имели в виду. Я про фразу "По это самое решение, то есть авторский выбор подходящей формы". И ещё я буду вам очень благодарен, если скажете своё мнение по поводу того, что я написал Римме. Первые вопросы к другому её ответу.

Comment: Про ваш ответ Римме чуть позже, а то сейчас со временем никак, хорошо?

Comment: Да, конечно, Шарон! На самом деле у меня такое ощущение, что вы сейчас так же рассуждали, как и я, то есть, можно сказать, признали однородность средней части и отсутствие запятой. И насчёт того, что к чему относится, думаю, согласитесь.

Comment: Артем, у нам с Риммой разное оформление, вы это видите (у меня нет первой запятой): Это чтО – стАрая форма и раньше только тАк говорили, или нЕт? А у нее вроде бы стоит эта запятая.  У Веры тоже стоит первая запятая, но у нее тире нет. Вам-то что сейчас ближе?

Comment: Зато в первом ответе Римма предлагает тире, и она первая его предложила, но перед И у неё запятая. Я бы её тоже поощрил немного за тире, если б можно было.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой * Я бы её тоже поощрил немного за тире* — а что, непонятно, что интонационное тире может заменять запятую?

Comment: Сложный выбор. Есть тире, но очень сомнительная запятая; есть тире и нет запятой, но тире чужое.  А вот у Веры все на месте, ей тире не нужно, так как она "что" относит только к "старой форме".  И семь дней она не думала, а сразу дала ответ. Зря вы ей не поверили:))

Comment: Интонационное тире помогает разбить четыре вопросительные части на три группы, но оно НЕПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНО. Я его, пожалуй, уберу, если оно не мое. НЕТ  У МЕНЯ ТИРЕ!

Comment: Ну вот! Я вовсе не хотел сказать, что вы не имеете на него права! Хотел этому ответу дать приз уже сейчас, если вы не против, но и тире мне нравилась. Зачем было убирать?..

Comment: Давайте я его оставлю в качестве второго варианта?

Comment: Добро) Ну что, согласны, награждаю вас?))

Comment: Интонационное тире передаёт удивление.

Comment: Убираю тире, оно мне разонравилось.  Выбирайте, Артем, на свой вкус.  Не надо меня награждать....пока.

Comment: Ладно, подожду ещё. Если до окончания срока не награжу никого, потом поздно будет? Н**а**до не опоздать, да? Поправьте только, пожалуйста, наконец, то предложение, которое я процитировал сегодня после того, как вы мне предложили поправить самому. Это вторая часть вашего второго ответа с комментариями.

Comment: Артем,  извините,  я примерила тире, но мне  показалось, что оно делит предложение на две части, а там запятой вполне достаточно. Вы условия конкурса обязательно прочитайте,  там разные варианты рассматриваются. А предложение я поправлю, если его найду.

Comment: А вы сделайте поиск по каким-то словам из него.

Answer (score 2):

Комментарии

1. **Нет у союза И пояснительного значения?** Так отчего же нет? Ведь присоединительное  значение у него точно есть, даже у Пушкина встречается.
   А что такое присоединение? Да все что угодно, что дополняет нашу мысль, в том числе и пояснение.  **Вот и все доказательство.**

Союз  ТО ЕСТЬ  выглядит книжным, и в данном случае в разговорном варианте его  прекрасно заменил союз И.

2. **Старая форма?** В разговоре люди прекрасно понимают условную терминологию, не прибегая к ее точной расшифровке по словарю. Излишняя книжность в разговоре также не приветствуется и выглядит нарушением стиля.
3. **И об ударениях.** Сравним:

Это старая форма или нЕт?

Это чтО, стАрая форма, или нЕт?

Это чтО, стАрая форма,  // и раньше только тАк говорили, // или нЕт?

Как мы видим,  запятая перед  ИЛИ может не ставиться, но это от структуры предложения зависит, а еще от желания автора выделить ударением предыдущее слово.

Это как раз тот пример **непримиримого противостояния** сторонников двух традиций  – ревнителей формальных и неприкасаемых правил и тех художников слова,  которые видит в знаках возможность выразить истинное звучание речи.

4. **Я считаю верными примеры у Веры:**

*Дядя в вас влюблЁн, или нЕт? МОжешь шагу прибавить, или силЁнок нет? Ты пОнял меня, или удАрить тебя?*

Семантика и структура этих предложений требует именной такой расстановки логических ударений и запятых, и автор имеет полное право на собственное понимание конкретной ситуации.  Трудно сказать, где здесь авторский вариант, а где правленный многочисленными редакторами. Истина верна только в определенных пределах – об этом стоит помнить.

Есть, правда, у Веры  **некоторая неточность** в рассуждениях, а именно: не стоило ей **обобщать** ситуацию для **всех разделительных союзов**. Как мы видим, все решается индивидуально и зависит от структуры предложения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ**

1. Артем, если вы не ставите запятую, то должны прочитать оба предложения в **одну фонетическую фразу**, то есть с одним основным ударением на весь текст. Конечно, есть промежуточные паузы и соответствующие им ударения, но они чисто **произносительного** характера.

Текст имеет **спокойную интонацию** и обычно подходит для **делового общения**. Пожалуй, только  последнее предложение можно так прочитать, безо всяких эмоций (они там подчеркнуто не нужны):

«*Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вАм? Дядя в вас влюблён или нЕт? Можешь шагу прибавить или силЁнок нет? Ты понял меня или удАрить тебя?»*

**Но это само решение**, то есть авторский выбор подходящей формы. А если требуется **официальное обоснование**, то всегда можно сказать, что союз ИЛИ здесь – **присоединительный, а не разделительный**. Любопытно было бы услышать, какие будут возражения.

2. oleedd,  что вы так разволновались из-за этой "зачетной" вставки?

***Это чтО, старая фОрма, //то есть раньше только так говорили //, или нЕт?***

Это не главная конструкция,  лежащая в основе предложения, а **второй ее план – вот что важно!** У нее свободный статус и структура, это дополнительные объяснения по поводу выражения  «старая форма».

Можете считать, что это вообще вставная конструкция, обособленная запятыми (Розенталь  разрешает).

**Вставочную интонацию** второго плана слышите? Это общее понижение тона и измененный темп речи.

Comment: Важно не то, верные ли примеры, а то, возможно ли в них без запятой. Так вот возможно только в первом. Пояснение не присоединяется союзом И. И не может быть равносильным ТО ЕСТЬ. Вы же чтите грамматику и особенно классификации — нет И в списке пояснительных союзов, потому что оно там не клеится (иначе бы написали "*и* в значении *то есть*"). Похоже, что вы любую новую информацию считаете пояснением.

Comment: Спасибо! А в предложении по ссылке, которую я привёл тогда же, когда и про дядю и др. спрашивал, не нужна? И можно поподробнее, какая именно расстановка логических ударений и пр. требует запятой, а когда она не нужна? Иными словами, как определять, нужна или нет?

Comment: *что вы так разволновались из-за этой "зачетной" вставки?* — потому что люблю, когда всё правильно. Разговор о вставной конструкции предвидел ещё в своём первом примечании (под вопросом), это нелепо, тогда в ней не должно быть вопросительной интонации. Ваш вариант с "то есть" принимаю, хотя не очень логично, потому что даже при старой форме могли говорить как-то иначе тоже. Но вы не слышите, что у И не может быть значения ТО ЕСТЬ. Если следствие (а не пояснение) — то да.

Comment: О примере "*Ты понял меня или удАрить тебя?*". Если прочитать в одну фразу, то основным в первой части становится последнее слово — "меня" (то есть *меня, а не кого-то другого*), а ударение должно падать на "понял" (надо его там поставить), в связи с этим без запятой там всё-таки не получается. Верно? Так может, для объединения вопросов необходимо, чтобы в первом ударение было на последнем слове? В этом примере и про шаг как раз так не получается, а в остальных двух — наоборот. А с запятыми получается аналогично.

Comment: У меня-то  все строго. Есть базоваая конструкция: «Это что, старая форма, или нет?»  Союз ИЛИ – присоединительный. Также есть обособленная  вставка второго плана  «и раньше только так говорили», что весьма характерно для разговорной речи.  Это всё. А что есть у вас? Вашего синтаксического разбора я вообще не видела.  И вот это мне строгим подходом к грамматике уже не кажется.

Comment: Ты понял меня / или удАрить тебя?  Без запятой все читаем с ровной интонацией, произносительная пауза в середине и единственное ударение в конце фразы. Никаких эмоций, спокойный и равнодушный тон. Вот такую палитру красок дает нам возможность одна-единственная запятая, которую правила предлагают нам ставить везде и всюду.

Comment: Не стоит путать вставку (это как комментарий к тексту) и присоединение (если по каким-то причинам в речи была пауза). Вы бы поставили там два тире (запятые вместо тире — это как редкие исключения, о чём сказано у Розенталя, как авторская пунктуация)? Если вставка, то там не должно быть вопросительной интонации. Она у вас есть? Насчёт примера. Вы не поняли мою мысль. Там два варианта: *ты пОнял меня?; ты понял менЯ* (а не кого-то другого). Так вот при объединении получается последнее, а оно нам не подходит, и приходится специально ставить ударение на "понял", из-за чего нужна запятая.

Comment: Почему вы не прокомментировали необходимость сместить ударение с конца фразы (которое получается, если просто читать без ударения)? Опять кидаете... С кем же мне самые сложные вещи обсуждать?

Comment: Чуть позже oleedd, ОК?   А то  голова уже ничего не соображает. Странный получился конкурс  – просто вавилонское столпотворение.  Опыта проведения таких мероприятий нет, кто и что обсуждает – непонятно. Но чуть позже – обязательно!

Comment: ВАРИАНТ БЕЗ ЗАПЯТОЙ: Ты понял меня / или удАрить тебя?
Сравним: Ты понял меня / или тебя удАрить?  Это обычное фразовое ударение на КОНЕЧНОМ слове, но логического выделения здесь нет, и поэтому предложение звучит совсем невыразительно. И тогда мы смещаем ударение на предыдущее слово, теперь фразовое ударение стало ЛОГИЧЕСКИМ, и оно выделяет нужное нам (ключевое) слово.

Comment: ВАРИАНТ С ЗАПЯТОЙ: Но первая часть без запятой по-прежнему произносится спокойным тоном, без эмоций –  ведь там вообще нет ни одного ударения. Чтобы выделить  глагол «понял», (а именно он является КЛЮЧЕВЫМ словом), надо сделать паузу и поставить запятую: Ты пОнял меня, / или удАрить тебя? Теперь оба ключевых слова под ударением, фраза произносится с большей экспрессией.

Comment: Получается, что вы тоже так считаете (что для выделения глагола "понял" — а это требуется по смыслу — **обязательна** запятая). Просто у вас в ответе сказано "*Пожалуй, только последнее предложение можно так прочитать, безо всяких эмоций*", это меня напрягло, ведь тогда будет смысл "понял меня, а не кого-то другого", а он нам не подходит.

Comment: Без запятой на слове "понял" будет интонационное , но ослабленное ударения. А если поставить запятую, то  это будет полноценное фразовое ударение, оно эмоционально подчеркивает слово.

Comment: Очень вас прошу исправить предложение или сказать, как его правильно читать, Шарон. Неприятно, когда непонятна мысль фрагмента вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Из ответов и комментариев я поняла, что акцент в предложении должен быть на *ст**а**рой форме*: это ст**а**рая форма или нет ("нет" в этом случае имеет значение "не старая").

Из вопроса:
*В первой* [запятой] *после "что" я не сомневаюсь, интересуют две оставшихся.*
А вот я сомневаюсь. Чтобы *однозначно* выделить нашу "старую форму", я бы вместо запятой поставила **тире**.

Такое оформление, считаю, вполне возможно:
*Кто мог подумать, что мы будем идти задом вперед, что ткнемся мордой в капитализм девятнадцатого века? **Это что — наш идеал?*** (А. Вознесенский);
*— Что-что? — вежливо произнес капитан и даже головой помотал, будто воду из ушей вытряхивал. — Что за чепуха! **Это что — «Риголетто»?*** (Д. Рубина).

Перед союзом "и" **надо** ставить запятую — так как он является в этом предложении присоединительным. Если же не ставить, то возникает "неправильная однородность" ("старая форма" и "раньше только так говорили").

Перед "или" запятая также необходима.
Если же оставить без обособления, то смысл будет таким: и раньше только так говорили или нет ("нет" в этом случае будет иметь значение "не только так", "по-другому").

**Это что — старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?**

[Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120)

P. S. Мне кажется, что правильно в вопросе надо было написать так: [меня] *интересуют две **оставшиеся*** [запятые].

Comment: Спасибо большое, Римма! Сейчас поправлю. А почему однородность неправильная? Может, именно однородность и нужна?

Comment: В комментарии не уместится. Я оформила дополнительный ответ. Благодарю за вопрос — потормошила мозги.

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнительный ответ** (после комментария *Артёма*)
*А почему однородность неправильная? Может, именно однородность и нужна?*

Думаю, что теоретически однородность возможна. Тогда фраза "это что" будет общей.
Это что, старая форма? Это что, раньше только так говорили?

[Нашла у Пелевина («Бэтман Аполло») предложение с глаголом:
*— В качестве молотка? — спросил я. — Это что, головой гвозди забивать?*]

Получаем:
*Это что, старая форма и раньше только так говорили?* (Или нет?)

Хорошо. А как быть с "или нет"? К чему мы его отнесем, к какой из частей?
Ставим запятую перед "или" — вопрос тогда относится к обоим предложениям, не ставим (а это, предполагаю, возможно) — только к последнему.
Если я правильно поняла, то вы хотели, чтобы "или нет?" относилось к "старой форме".
При такой пунктуации вопросительное слово зависнет — останется только догадываться, в чем именно автор сомневается.

Comment: Да не будет фраза "это что" общей (и для фразы этого маловато): это нелепо, сочетание "это что" одно из тех, что тесно примыкают к следующей фразе, как и противительный союз. У Пелевина смысл "это что значит". Правила позволяют нам соединять два вопроса, если хочется спросить о двух вещах: *Это старая форма? Раньше только так говорили?* Почему вы против? Похожий пример: *Это крокодил Гена и он играет на гармошке?* Структура вопроса: *это так и это так?*

Comment: Спасибо! Да, "раньше только так и говорили" поясняет "старую форму", то есть я фактически говорю об одном и том же разными словами. Поэтому однородность кажется вполне подходящей. Таким образом, "это что" относится к обоим этим элементам и "или нет" тоже к ним обоим относится, только с разных сторон.

Comment: @oleedd Разве я где-нибудь в ответе сказала, что я **против** отсутствия запятой перед "и"? Совсем наоборот.  _Это что, старая форма и раньше только так говорили? (Или нет?)_ Я только пыталась разобраться, каково же будет в этом случае значение последующего вопроса "или нет?". Посмотрите: _Ставим запятую перед "или" — вопрос тогда относится к обоим предложениям..._ Мне кажется, что только **после** этого моего ответа _Sharon_ и сделала точно такой же, но уже как бы _свой, окончательный вариант_.

Comment: Ну вы же говорили про какую-то "неправильную однородность", которая мешает не ставить запятую перед И (в другом ответе). Я о однородности без общего элемента, а вы вроде бы против. Доказательство, что "это что" не общий элемент, такое: *Это что, раньше только так говорили и старая форма?* Требуется повтор "это что", оно примыкает только к первому вопросу. А "или нет" — да, без запятой имеет смысл "или не говорили". Если будет три запятые, то "или нет" может также относится только ко второму вопросу. Ещё интересно то, что интонационное тире вместо первой запятой передаёт удивление.

Answer (score 1):

Вера не права, что разделительный союз не может объединять предложения.
Правило Розенталя:
Запятая перед соединительным и **разделительным** союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
1) вопросительные предложения: *Это кто такие и что им надобно?* (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; *Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне **или** мне прийти к вам?*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

Перед И запятую лучше не ставить, тогда получается единый вопрос:
*Это старая форма и раньше только так говорили?*
Если будет запятая, то будут два отдельных вопроса, и тогда непонятно, к чему будет относится "или нет?": к первому, к последнему (так по структуре) или к обоим. То есть возможны варианты, что будет зависеть от интонации.
Запятая может здесь ставится для присоединения: то есть если второй вопрос возник не сразу, а чуть позже, в процессе произнесения этого предложения, — чтобы передать то, как было сказано на самом деле.

А про запятую перед ИЛИ такая подсказка: если "или нет" можно оформить как новое предложение (а здесь это очень уместно), то это не однородный элемент, а присоединение. Здесь оно чёткое. А тут запятая не нужна:
*Нам заплатят сегодня или нет?*

То есть необходимо различать присоединение и неоднородность вопроса.

Comment: Попробую объяснить пример у Vera. Там не все так просто и однозначно, как кажется. (1) Дядя в вас влюблЁн, или нЕт? Очень эмоциональный и трогательный вопрос, девушка ведь волнуется… Запятая ставится, так как союз ИЛИ здесь присоединительный. (2) Дядя в вас влюблён или нЕт? Ну просто как на допросе, никакой лирики. Это разделительный союз, запятая не ставится.Да и вообще, разделительный союз – это загадка природы, с ним и лингвисты до конца еще не разобрались.

Comment: И еще oleedd. Запишите, пожалуйста,  в начале ответа ваш вариант или варианты, которые вы обсуждаете.

Comment: Спасибо! Про неоднородность не понял, где тут противопоставление? И ещё: у меня не просто "это", а "это что", после которого ты не привык почему-то ставить запятую.))

Comment: @Sharon Это тоже заметил, и сразу, но вариант 2 чего-то показался разговорным, поэтому не стал об этом говорить. Какие варианты записать (вообще не понял)?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А вот мне хотелось "не [есть] права" отдельно, так тоже можно. Однородность — это когда можно поменять предложения местами (в идеале), когда они похожи и, главное, когда нет присоединения. Про противопоставление ничего не говорил. "Что" можно вернуть на место, просто без него пример яснее.

Comment: @oleedd  Это вообще разговорная речь  (ее содержание вполне понятно).  Но она тоже нормируется, а записывать ее еще труднее, чем обычную.  Я понимаю задачу так. Надо выбрать вариант записи (свой или Артема), расставить знаки препинания и объяснить их. Объяснение Веры  у Артема вызывает сомнение. Вот и запишите по порядку  один или два варианта и приведите комментарии для каждого (так легче будет их сравнивать и разбираться).

Comment: @Sharon Я уже в понятие "разговорный" вкладываю смысл "не совсем правильный". Уже ж сказал, для чего может ставиться запятая. Второй абзац про варианты. Не вижу смысла всё переделывать.

Comment: Как хотите.  Может быть, Артему понравится ваш ответ, как знать.

Comment: *Может быть, Артему понравится ваш ответ* — уже или понравился, или нет. Но за непонравившийся спасибо не говорят.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Артем, вы какую форму имели в виду  (устаревшее слово, неправильное ударение или  целую фразу)?

Comment: Разговорная речь – это особый стиль речи, не надо отождествлять с просторечием. Мне нравится такое ее описание. https://zen.yandex.ru/media/gramotnost/razgovornaia-rech-i-prostorechie-chto-eto-takoe-5d9717f47cccba00c4c796c7

Comment: @Sharon: не понял что-то вопроса, простите. О какой форме речь?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса:  "Это что, старая форма..."

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, интересно. Никак не мог понять грань, так оказывается, что и у учёных она не чётко определена.

Comment: Специально не переходил по ссылке. Для меня разговорная речь – это совсем не неправильная речь, и, конечно, не просторечие. "Ихний" может быть просторечием или юмором (это зависит от ситуации), а вот "комп", "магаз", "коммент" – это именно разговорные слова, которые, на мой взгляд, могут перейти в разряд нормативных (и даже литературных) спустя какое-то время. Язык движется к лаконичности, быстроте и пр.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тогда как назвать неправильную, но употребляемую, например "упорно не могу"? Давайте не о словах, а о фразах. Википедия говорит, что просторечие — это грубоватые слова.

Comment: Аааа! Это из [этого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419361/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%94%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f) вопроса, Шарон.

Answer (score 1):

Артем, это **полный список ответов и их сравнение**. Надеюсь, он поможет вам определиться с решением.

**1. Ответ Веры**

***Это что, старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Местоимение «что» относится только к «старой форме», поэтому она обособляется.
Базовый вариант: *Это старая форма и раньше только так говорили, или нет?*
Здесь разделительный союз  ИЛИ приходится считать присоединительным.

**2. Мой первый ответ**

***Это что, старая форма, и  раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Местоимение «что» относится только к «старой форме», поэтому она обособляется. Но обособляется и вставная конструкция  *и раньше только так говорили*. Смысла в двойном обособлении нет, поэтому я изменила ответ.

В этом варианте союз ИЛИ можно считать разделительным.

**3. Мой второй  ответ**

***Это что, старая форма и  раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Обособляется; *старая форма и  раньше только так говорили.*

Местоимение «что» относится **ко всей фразе**  «старая форма и  раньше только так говорили», поэтому она  обособляется.

В этом варианте союз ИЛИ можно считать разделительным.

**4. Ответ Риммы**

***Это что — старая форма, и раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Я этот вариант не комментирую, он мне до конца неясен.

**5. Ответ oleedd**

Записи нет, но насколько я поняла, он допускает такой вариант:

***Это что, старая форма и  раньше только так говорили, или нет?***

Перед И он запятую не ставит, перед ИЛИ допускает запятую (по принципу однородный или неоднородный элемент, соединение или присоединение).

Фактически мой второй ответ и ответ oleedd совпадают, но объяснения разные.

Comment: Вы предложение можете-таки поправить, Шарон?

Comment: Спасибо за подведение итогов!

Comment: Пожалуйста, Артем. Я бы не стала подводить никаких итогов, если бы знала, о каком предложении идет речь. Итоги я могу убрать,  если они вас не очень интересуют и вы не возражаете против этого (наверное, вам и без них все ясно). А вы мне точно скажите координаты предложения, подлежащего правке, а именно: 1) какой это ответ из данных мною; 2) его примерное расположение на поле (номер, например), 3) цитату хотя бы начала этого предложения.  Извините, мне жаль, что мы никак не разберемся с этой проблемой.

Comment: Введите в поиск "По это самое решение". Меня этот момент тоже напряг, уже показалось, что чего-то не знаю (вдруг некое устойчивое выражение). Потом: у меня перед И можно как с запятой, так и без неё, а перед ИЛИ она обязательна, а принципы вы хорошо указали. Вопрос Артёма про то, является ли его вариант правильным (возможным), следовательно, необходимо указать все возможные.

Comment: Посмотрите, пжста, я правильно исправила?

Comment: Да, правильно...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Там ещё дальше вроде как нужно заменить И (его ж нет там) на ИЛИ.

Comment: Ура, Шарон, наконец-то! Спасибо! Ещё там следующее предложение тоже начинается с НО — не очень, но если вы устали исправлять))), то пускай остаётся так. Впрочем, я дерзнул заменить его на А, если возражаете, сделайте на свой вкус. ;)

Comment: Всё, хватит тянуть кота за хвост)

Comment: Спасибо, Артем за доверие,  я думаю, что вы выбрали то, что вам действительно нравится. Спасибо!! Очень трудно проводить конкурсы, не правда ли? Решитесь еще когда-нибудь на такой подвиг? :)

Comment: На здоровье! Посмотрим там))

Answer (score 0):

Выделяем *старую форму,* потому что про нее и спрашивают, и отделяем или нет, потому что чередование: да или нет.