# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом?

Tags: пунктуация

*А что Вы, собственно, пытаетесь доказать(,) и кому?*

Подразумевается: «Кому Вы это хотите доказать!?»

Или надо дописывать это полностью, чтобы фраза была правильной?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> А что Вы, собственно, пытаетесь доказать(,) и кому?

По-моему, стоит сделать так:

***А что Вы, собственно, пытаетесь доказать? И кому?***

Comment: Спасибо, Слава, хорошая идея!

Answer (score 2):

А что Вы, собственно, пытаетесь доказать, и кому?

Присоединительный член предложения можно обособить запятой, наверное, не обязательно делить предложение на части.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_690), слово *собственно* вводное и потому разделяется запятыми. Перед *и* запятая не нужна, потому что, если мы переставим *и кому*, получится следующее:

> А что и кому Вы, собственно, пытаетесь...

То есть получаются однородные члены предложения. Даже если считать так, как вы предложили (про подразумевание), то запятая всё равно бы не ставилась, потому что эти два предложения содержат вопрос ([см.](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/474)).

Comment: Про "собственно" я и так понимаю, вопрос был про запятую в скобках только. А по делу: вроде есть правила, по которым она не ставится, но в то же время тут было обсуждение, что эти правила спорные, и есть противоположные рекомендации на этот счёт.

Comment: Вот хоть Верин ответ на мой вопрос: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419367/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-999

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, что запятая факультативна. Считаем однородными членами - не ставим, считаем присоединительной конструкцией - ставим. Я бы 50/50 (то есть трудный выбор).