# Запятая в ССП, но не полноценном, а с подразумеваемой правой частью

Tags: пунктуация

Написал такое предложение:

*Я тоже, как любой человек, ошибаюсь, и не редко.*

Я правильно поставил запятую перед *"и не редко"* или нет? Руководствовался, во-первых, интуицией (которая может и врать...), а во-вторых, тем, что правая часть неполная, имеется в виду *"и ошибаюсь я нередко".* Кстати, полностью получилось "нередко" слитно, но мне почему-то кажется, что так правильно (по-разному).

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это простое предложение с присоединительной конструкцией **и не редко**. Она содержит дополнительное замечание. Ср. у Розенталя Д. Э. *Дело мы делаем великое и сделали уже немало, а недостатки есть ― и серьезные*. Запятую Вы поставили правильно, возможно еще тире.

Answer (score 3):

***Я тоже, как любой человек, ошибаюсь  — и не редко.***

См. [**ПАС**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/):

> **§ 85. Присоединительные члены** предложения, не имеющие специальных вводящих слов и выступающие в качестве разъясняющих добавочных
>   сообщений, **отделяются** знаком **тире**. Они стоят в конце предложения:
>
> *Старуха приняла кончину шарика как судьбу – не больше и не меньше...*

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже, как любой человек, ошибаюсь, **и не редко.**

Это простое предложение, "и не редко" ― **обособленное обстоятельство**, И ― **присоединительный союз**.